# How to split one Kafka topic into multiple smaller Kafka topics?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, kafka-producer-api

I have one main Kafka topic that receives some time series data. I need to take each value that comes into that topic, copy it, and send it to one of many separate topics based on a value in its key. Since it's time series data, each entry has a timestamp in its value. How can I accomplish this split while ensuring that the values pushed into the separate topics don't get out of order in respect to their timestamp?

Comment: Have you seen this example? https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/4.1.x/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/MapFunctionLambdaExample.java since this is a stateless operation you're doing, I think it's helpful

Comment: Using Kafka Streams, you can either user `KStream#branch`() to `KStream#to` with `TopicNameExtractor` (note, `TopicNameExtractor` was added recently into Kafka 2.0.0 release and is not available in older versions).

Comment: The dynamic topic branching with the TopicNameExtractor almost solves my problem. The issue I have is that the topic name it needs to extract is not in the topic I'm streaming. I have a second topic that acts as a lookup where the Key in the topic I'm streaming is the same key in the lookup topic. The value of the lookup topic is what contains the topic name. What is the best way to handle the dynamic topic branching where the topic name is in another topic?

Answer (score 2):

True. With kafkaStreams you can continuously read from any topic in the broker, process the data with a conditional (based in your case in the id) and write back to the broker in any other output topics. Optionally, to check results in them you can subscribe to these output topics from any other listener. Is easy and fast.

Answer (score 0):

You could use KSQL and create new topics with the SQL query:

```
CREATE STREAM pageviews(
    viewtime BIGINT KEY,
    userid VARCHAR,
    pageid VARCHAR
  ) WITH (
    KAFKA_TOPIC='pageviews',
    VALUE_FORMAT='DELIMITED',
    PARTITIONS=4,
    REPLICAS=3
  );
```

https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/create-a-stream/

Or as @Matthias J. Sax mentioned with KStreams:
https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html